# $X, Y$ be sets, $f:X→Y$ surjective map. For every $y ∈ Y$ , we put $Xy = f^{−1}(y)$. prove $Xy$ define partition of $X$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let $X$, $Y$ be sets, $f:X \to Y$ be a surjective map. For every $y \in Y$ , we put $Xy = f^{−1}(y)$. Prove that the sets $Xy$ define a partition of $X$?

my try:

since $f$ is surjective every $x$ has only one image in $Y$

since every $y$ in $Y$ has one or more pre-images

that means intersections between subsets containing in $X$ is empty set
and the union between them is $X$

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange! You may use LaTeX-Formulas by using dollar signs \$ x^2 \$ gives $x^2$, for instance. Braces {} are useful for grouping. Look at how I've edited your first sentence for examples.

Answer (score 2):

Your proof needs work. Try writing out the things you need to prove, like

(a) The sets $Xy$ (for $y \in Y$) contain every element of $X$.

(b) No set $Xy$ is empty

(c) If $Xy$ and $Xy'$ intersect, then they are equal.

Those three properties make these subsets a partition. Your first statement is almost a proof of a and b. Try to clean it up a bit and see if you can write it out in clear declarative sentences.